# Processing instruction not closed error in html

Tags: html, eclipse

Hi i am very new to developing , I started to type HTML code in eclipse but it showing processing instruction not closed error .I don't know how to solve please help me .. Thanks in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <div class="banner_page">
         <div style="width: 90%; margin: 16px 0px 16px 104px;"></div>
         <div class="header_menu">
            <div style="float: left;">
               <ul>
                  <li>Home</li>
                  <li>Pages</li>
                  <li>Mega menu</li>
                  <li>Gallery</li>
                  <li>Blog</li>
                  <li>Support</li>
                  <li>Contact</li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: At the very least you need to show us what you typed.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.banner_page
{
float: left;
width: 100%;
height: 900px;
background-color: #26455F;

}
.header_menu
{
background-color: rgb(242,85,73);
height: 82px;

}
body {
 margin: 0px;
}
.phone
{
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 14px;

}

</style>

</head>
<body>
<div class="banner_page">
<div style="width: 90%; margin: 16px 0px 16px 104px;">
</div>
<div class="header_menu">
<div style="float: left;">
<ul>
<li>Home</li>
<li>Pages</li>
<li>Mega menu</li>
<li>Gallery</li>
<li>Blog</li>
<li>Support</li>
<li>Contact</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div></body>
</html>

Comment: @greg Above i copied the code which i typed

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @EmeryFramboise  In eclipse it showing the error that processing instruction not closed error .. how to close that .. i closed all the opened <div> tag .. i don't know what is the actual error

Comment: Try selecting all, deleting everything, save, ctrl/cmd -z, save.

Comment: `Ctrl+A` then `Ctrl+x` and finally `Ctrl+v`, there you go!

Comment: Nothing syntactically wrong in your HTML code. Rather appear to be a bug in Eclipse IDE. You may try few work around as suggested above. FYI: I tried this on a latest eclipse and didn't complain anything. Probably you might also need to consider upgrading IDE to the latest

Answer (score 9):

Select all your code, then <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd>, then <kbd>CTRL+Z</kbd> to revert back the changes.

Comment: Surprisingly `Ctrl+A` `Ctrl+X` `Ctrl+S` `Ctrl+V` `Ctrl+S` will also remove such errors, with less hovering above keyboard.

Answer (score 4):

Just close the JSP tab and reopen it will solve

Answer (score 2):

1. Select all your code <kbd>CTRL+A</kbd>, copy it <kbd>CTRL+С</kbd>.
2. Delete original file.
3. Create a new file with the same name, paste <kbd>CTRL+V</kbd> the copied code and save changes.

Answer (score 1):

I tabbed your code out and it appears you are missing a closing DIV tag

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
    <div class="banner_page">
        <div style="width: 90%; margin: 16px 0px 16px 104px;"></div>
            <div class="header_menu">
                <div style="float: left;">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Home</li>
                        <li>Pages</li>
                        <li>Mega menu</li>
                        <li>Gallery</li>
                        <li>Blog</li>
                        <li>Support</li>
                        <li>Contact</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
   <!-- you need another closing div tag here for banner_page -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The div on the second line is being closed in the same line

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of the error by the following steps...

1. Ctrl + All
2. Ctrl + x
3. Ctrl + save
4. close the html file
5. Reopen the same html file
6. Now save the cut code from the former

Now all the errors disappeared